# Application with full screen mode in Jetpack Compose

Tags: dialog, android-jetpack-compose, popupwindow, android-fullscreen

I'm currently building an application in **jetpack compose** which requires full screen mode throughout the app.
Problem is whenever a dialog or popup appears status bar and navigation bar gets visible i.e. application goes out from full screen mode.

I've tried "**SystemUiController**" to hide both but I've to do it manually on every popup screen. Is there any way that application handles full screen popup and dialogs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to make my app fullscreen, per [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive):

```
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
            .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
```

In the MainActivity, it can look like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        SampleAppTheme {
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
                    .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

                SampleApp()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}